# JPA query in Play for Scala throws compilation error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to implement a JPA query in Play for Scala. I took the information from [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA), but since the examples are in Java I'm probably mistaken. This is the code:

```
class ManageBanks @Inject() (jpaApi: JPAApi) extends Controller {

   @Transactional
   def readMany = {
      val em = jpaApi.em

      jpaApi.withTransaction( (em: EntityManager) => {   //  <-- error in this line
          val query = em.createQuery("from BankHib order by name")
          val list = query.getResultList.asScala.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[BankHib])
          list
      })
   }
}
```

I get the following error when I compile:

> overloaded method value withTransaction with alternatives: [T](x$1:
>   String, x$2: Boolean, x$3: java.util.function.Supplier[T])T 
>   (x$1: Runnable)Unit  [T](x$1: java.util.function.Supplier[T])T
>    [T](x$1: String, x$2: Boolean, x$3:
>   java.util.function.Function[javax.persistence.EntityManager,T])T 
>   [T](x$1: String, x$2:
>   java.util.function.Function[javax.persistence.EntityManager,T])T 
>   [T](x$1:
>   java.util.function.Function[javax.persistence.EntityManager,T])T
>   cannot be applied to (javax.persistence.EntityManager ⇒
>   List[admin.manage.BankHib])

What's wrong with this code? How to make the query work?

Comment: What if you replace (em: EntityManager) => to em -> only

Comment: that doesn't fix the problem as `->` in Scala is used for Map structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `play.db.jpa.JPAApi.withTransaction` has the following signatures:

1. `withTransaction(java.util.function.Function<javax.persistence.EntityManager,T>)`
2. `withTransaction(java.lang.String, java.util.function.Function<javax.persistence.EntityManager,T>)`
3. `withTransaction(java.lang.String, boolean, java.util.function.Function<javax.persistence.EntityManager,T>)`
4. `withTransaction(java.util.function.Supplier<T>)`
5. `withTransaction(java.lang.Runnable)`
6. And finally `withTransaction(java.lang.String, boolean, java.util.function.Supplier<T>)`.

But you are instead passing a Scala function of type `(javax.persistence.EntityManager ⇒ List[admin.manage.BankHib])`. So, wrong type and the compiler complains saying that it was not able to find an alternative.

The correct way then is to use a `java.util.function.Function[EntityManager, List]`:

```
class ManageBanks @Inject()(jpaApi: JPAApi) extends Controller {

  def readMany = {
    jpaApi.withTransaction(new java.util.function.Function[EntityManager, List[BankHib]] {
      override def apply(em: EntityManager): List[BankHib] = {
        val query = em.createQuery("from BankHib order by name")
        query.getResultList.asScala.map(_.asInstanceOf[BankHib]).toList
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Also, notice that you don't need to mix `JPAApi` and `JPA` to get an `EntityManager` since `JPAApi` has methods that already provides it to the given function.

Comment: So there's no need to close the EntityManager?

Comment: @ps0604 no need to close it. Play handles that for you.

Comment: And I assume that I don't need to initiate/commit a transaction because that's covered implicitly by `@Transactional`

Comment: Yes, you can remove `@Transactional` here.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
class ManageBanks @Inject() (jpaApi: JPAApi) extends Controller {

   @Transactional
   def readMany = {


      jpaApi.withTransaction( () => {   //  <-- error in this line
          val em = JPA.em() // or jpaApi.em
          val query = em.createQuery("from BankHib order by name")
          val list = query.getResultList.asScala.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[BankHib])
          list
      })
   }
}
```